# Redirect to another page on submit JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase-authentication

I am trying to integrate firebase auth in node js express based application.

But I am getting this error:

> nexttick.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'redirect' of
>   undefined

This is my `register.js` file:

```
signUpForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //get user info
    const email = signUpForm["email"].value;
    const password = signUpForm["password"].value;

    //sign up the user
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((req, res) => {
        res.redirect('/');
    })
});
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you may refer to the [new API](https://gist.github.com/zenorocha/9282426622fc8f46a6caeff40008de75) version

Comment: simply use global window object as ```window.location = "/"``` or  ```window.location.pathname = "/YOUR URL"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` the wrong way. The method is a promise so it's okay to attach a `.then` or `.catch` to it, however, from what I saw in the docs, `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` promise does not resolve to a `req` or `res` parameters like you added to the `.then` method and it rejects when there is an error in the create user process. So this is how you are supposed to use the method:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(() => {
  window.location.replace('/')
})
.catch((error) => {
  // Handle errors here.
});
```

You can take a look at [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#error-codes_3) for the possible types of errors that can be rejected.

For redirecting, you can make use of either the [`location.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) or [`location.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) API available as global variables in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly, a promise cannot return two or more values, here is an example

```js
new Promise((res) => res(1, 2, 3, 4))
      .then((a, b, c, d) => console.log(a, b, c, d));
```

The same story with a rejection in the promise, the output can be only one argument

```js
new Promise((_, rej) => rej(1, 2, 3, 4))
      .catch((a, b, c, d) => console.log(a, b, c, d));
```

Secondly, the method you use returns the `<UserCredential>` in the response, not the `request, response`. Here the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#create-user-with-email-and-password

How to make a redirect in a browser without express has already been suggested:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60316794/1431312